# getPocket API - iOS

Tags: ios, api, authentication

I am implementing the Pocket API so that users off my app can save web pages to the services.

Now I have it sorted that I can login and save pages, but as far as I can tell the documentation misses these 2 things:

- check if the user is logged in
- how the user can logout

Has anyone have any solutions to this? I will email Pocket themselves, but just seeing for opinions on the matter.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the user logs in i'm guessing you store the access token used to make API calls? To check if the user is logged in / has access check that the token exists and if they are able to make calls to the API without being refused access. To logout you would simply remove the token from whatever storage method you have in place.

Comment: ok - i'll look into that, it makes sense - just got to make it work:-)